# How to generate excel report me karate framework?

Tags: excel, report, karate

Is there any way to get karate report in Excel **or** In karate can we convert cucumber html report in excel?

I have tried with below code:

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"info.cukes.formatter.xls.XLSOutputFormatter"})

but the dependency for this is missing.
Below is the dependency which i tried to use.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-xls</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: karate is NOT cucumber. if you are willing to dig into java code, you may be able to create the report you want (see linked question) else please consider this as not supported.